# JQuery: Check value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the number entered in the input-field is higher of even as th value in my 'min' field?

```
            <tr>
                <td>Steeeeaak</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="amount_5_min" value="10"/>
                <input type="text" name="amount_5" size="4" value="10"/></td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td><a href="/item/delete/eventId/2/hash/a8b5dzp9rks7164wh30j2anqh13w/itemId/5">Verwijder</a> </td>
            </tr>
```

As you can see the first part of the name of both fields are the same ... Any possibilities here? I do a submit at the end of the form, so I guess I have to do something on submit?

Thx!

Comment: Are there lots of theses rows, like a shopping cart?

Comment: Indeed, there are a lot of these rows. I only put one row here to prevent too much code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fieldname = "amount_5";
var val1 = parseInt($("input[name="+field_name+"_min]").val(),10);
var val2 = parseInt($("input[name="+field_name+"]").val(),10);
// Compare the values
```

And to bind onto the submit action of the form

```
$("form#your_form_id_here").submit(function() {
    // Use above code
});
```

**EDIT** 
Kevin makes a good point

**EDIT 2**
Updated for any input name

Comment: It should probably be parseInt($..., 10) as someone could be 010 in the value, and that would convert it to octal and make 010 not equal to 10, even though they probably should be considered equal.

Comment: The problem is: There are many rows of this ... so I can't hardcode the names.

Comment: @kok See edit. Unless you meant you need to dynamically obtain the actual name of the field as well. Which is possible.

Comment: THx! I indeed need to get the names dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing by the markup you posted that there are many rows, shopping cart style.  In that case here's a way to loop though all rows checking the amounts on submit, just give your form/table IDs to match your selector:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  var valid = true;
  $("#myTable tr td input[name^='amount_']:last-child").each(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value, 10); //this value
    var min_val = parseInt($(this).siblings().val(), 10); //min_value
    if(val < min_val) {
      valid = false;
      alert($(this).closest('tr').children(':first').text() + //"Steeeeaak"
            " doesn't meet the minimum required value: " + min_val);
    }
  });
  return valid; //submit aborts if any didn't meet min value
});
```

This function makes use of the `<input>` elements being siblings, in a certain order and inside the same `<td>`, just using the known HTML structure to your advantage here.

Comment: Thanks! There are also a few different tables with different names... How to make that dynamically too?

Comment: You can leave the table ID off, or give them all the same class, e.g. `class="amountTable"` and use `.amountTable` instead of `#myTable` in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this one out there just for fun (and partly because I just learned about `~~` today).

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/694dB/

It assumes the inputs are the only two (or at least the first two) in the row.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    var $inputs = $(this).find('input[name^=amount]');

    var values = $inputs.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

       // If it is less than the minimum, add a class,
       //    and return false to stop the submit
    if(~~values[1] < ~~values[0]) {
        $inputs.closest('tr').addClass("someNewClassName");
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Updated based on your comment.** Please note, that this is effective for *one* row. To do the same operation on several rows, you'll need to use a loop like **@Nick** provided in his answer.

Article on the double bitwise operator:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/

Comment: Thx patrick! Your assumption is right, there are only 2 inpu-fields in a row. I tried the demo-code. It seems to be exactly what I need! Will try this after some sleep ;-)

Comment: @koko - Sounds good. Let me know how it turns out for you. :o)

Comment: When I put a value higher then min, I als get the alert 'meets the minimum'. Is it possible to add a class to the row with the error? If there is an error, it still submits at the moment. How can I tackle that? As you can seet, I'm pretty new to JQuery :$

Comment: @koko - I updated my answer to add a class and prevent the submit when there is an error. Let me know how it looks. :o)

Answer (score 0):

In that case, use something like:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //get all input tags
var texts;
var minlengths;
for (input in elms) {
    var value = input.value; //'with' statement is evil
    if (input.type == "text") {
        texts.push(value);
    } else if (input.type == "hidden") {
        minlengths[value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf("_"))] = value; //set what the field 'checks' = the minimum length
    }
}
for (text in texts) { //go back through the texts because the inputs might not be right after the texts
    var minlength = minlengths[text];
    var textnum = parseInt(text.value, 10);
    if (textnum === NaN || textnum > minlength) {
        alert("One of the fields is greater than the minimum length.");
    }
}
```

Note: This code is untested, and may not work. There is probably an "off by one" error somewhere in there.

Edit: In any case, you have to do this server-side too, because the user may tamper with the request. (Never trust the user)
<s>Is there any specific reason why you can't just use the `minlength` attribute on the text input fields?</s>

Comment: Hello71 - Is there such a thing? There's a maxlength, but I don't think there's a minlength. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp Anyway, the OP appears to want to compare numeric values, as in greater than / less than. Not the number of characters.

Comment: Why is `input.value` evil, as you state in your comment?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, it's the 'with' statement that's evil. I used `value = input.value` instead of `with input`.